# Valgrind on Tensorflow Lite invoke makes it run indefinitely

Tags: c++, tensorflow, valgrind, tensorflow-lite

I have a custom library that wraps either Tensorflow or Tensorflow Lite, depending on the device that should run a given network. Since the goal is to exports this library, I have continuous integration that at some point checks the leaks and any errors a valgrind run could return.

In that context, Valgrind seems to struggle running `TFL_InterpreterInvoke` from the 1.12.1 Tensorflow release. I simply have a warning `Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x14f33050, 0x2b0330d0) (undefined)` that tells me I allocated ~350Mo.

Is there a way to give valgrind a bigger address range? It seems tensorflow is doing `mmap` allocations, is this the issue, can I tell valgrind to not check those?

Comment: The warning is just a warning.  It is not shown if you decrease the valgrind verbosity using -q.  I suggest you use gdb+vgdb to see what your program does when running under valgrind.  See http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver for more info.

Comment: I've done that yes to at least get the trace and see where it stucks.

Comment: Has this shown anything ? Is your program still progressing ?

Comment: I am at home at the moment and ran valgrind for the night. I can get the trace fast since the error is at the beginning. I will edit my post with the trace tomorrow if I don't have a good surprise tomorrow morning.

Comment: The valgrind finally passed. I cannot explain why and how. I know valgring is longer than a normal run but here a normal run is about 3min and a valgrind run is 30min I didn't remember it could took so long. Does the valgrind overhead is directly linked to the amount of memory allocated (I use the memcheck tool) ?

Comment: A factor 10 is not unusual.  The slowdown can depend significantly on what your application does and what options you give to valgrind.  You might be interested to look at https://archive.fosdem.org/2015/schedule/event/valgrind_tuning/attachments/slides/743/export/events/attachments/valgrind_tuning/slides/743/tuning_V_for_your_workload.pdf

Comment: My CI will always run the same options: --leak-check=full, --track-origins=yes and --show-leak-kinds=definite,possible. I wasn't fully aware about the vgdb / gdb possibilities. Thanks for pointing that.